# Possible natural arguments: to show subgroup of order $m$ in group of order $2m$, $m$ odd

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

A simple interesting result in Group Theory on the existence of (normal) subgroup is following:

> If $|G|=2m$, $m$ odd, then $G$ has a (normal) subgroup of order $m$.

This theorem, as a problem/question, has been  appeared on StackExchange several times.

I know the proof, and when I saw the proofs in all the appeared answers in StackExchange, it is noticed that *the answers are same*.

So, I asked myself: *Is there a different proof of this theorem?*

I tried the following way, and feel that, the following arguments are very *natural ones*; but I couldn't complete.

Suppose, we know there is subgroup $H$ of order $m$ (odd). What can be said about this subgroup? Since $[G\colon H]=2$, the square of every element of $G$ will be in $H$. Conversely, if $x$ is any element of $H$, then being element of odd order, $x$ is a square.

It follows that $H$ is precisely the set of squares in $G$.

Now, I tried to prove the theorem in following way: it suffices to consider a subset 
$$S=\{g^2\colon g\in G\}$$
and prove that $S$ is a subgroup. In fact, it is sufficient to prove that $S$ is closed under product (since it is subset of *finite group*).

**Question:** Given $|G|=2m$, $m$ odd, can it be proved that the subset of squares in $G$ is closed under product, without using the arguments (or Cayley's theorem) of the quoted theorem above?

Comment: If is sufficient to prove : ord(a) odd and ord(b) odd $\implies$ ord(ab) odd because the squares of $G$ are the elements of odd order of $G$.